# Apple Configurator: "Lock to app" with ability to open external apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mdm, apple-configurator

So, I am using Apple configurator to lock the iPad only to my app.
The problem is that my app opens some external apps: like FB , games ...

When the functionality "Lock to app" is disabled , it is possible to open any external app using:
    NSString *stringURL = @"example://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

But, unfortunately, I can NOT open external app when the "Lock to app" functionality is enable.

Is there any solution to keep using the "Lock to app" while being able to open external apps (only from my app since the user can not access to the home screen)
or is there any solution that works without using "Lock to app" but force using only my app.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to create a springboard-type app. I don't think you can accomplish it with mdm - jailbreaking would probably be required to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2):

So the lock to app option will lock you into only that app and there is no way currently to whitelist or lock to multiple apps or apps that are opened by calls from within the locked app.  You should write an enhancement request to Apple in their bug report system.

Currently, your best option if you dev the app would be to use autonomous single app mode (check out WWDC 2014's Designing Apps for Education and Enterprise talk) and have your app disable single app mode right before it makes an external URL call.  When the user comes back to the app, you'd lock them back into single app mode on launch and to disable single app mode you could use managed app configuration to send a signal to the app.  To prevent the users from wandering around too much when you've turned off single app mode to allow them to go to an external app, you should probably use as many restrictions as possible to remove unnecessary system apps (like Camera, App Store, etc) and prevent app installation and deletion (after ensuring your necessary apps are installed on device).  Not exactly elegant, hence why I'd suggest writing a bug to Apple, but could fit your needs depending on your scenario.